# square over BottomNavigationBarItem when curser is above it (flutter web)

Tags: flutter, web

I've created a flutter web app and I'm using a scaffold with a bottomnavigationbar. But every time my curser is above a bottomnavigationbaritem there appears a square above it. What is that square and how can I remove it?

[Here you can see the square I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHJlc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) documentation in Flutter.

The constructor has showSelectedLabels = true by default, just pass it to be false in your constructor.
To be safe, you can also pass showUnselectedLabels = false.
[image]